# Read a file and replace dot with colon using sed command

Tags: linux, command-line, regex, sed

Im trying to read and substitute period(.) with colon (:) from the below input file using sed regex expression.
Can one please check and suggest me.

Input File has `12.23.45`
Expected  is `12:34:78`

Below is the sed regex expression I have tried :

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)\.\([0-9][0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\[0-9]\)/\1\:\2\:\3/g' TestFile.txt
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra backslash before the last character class:

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)\.\([0-9][0-9]\)\.\([0-9]\[0-9]\)/\1\:\2\:\3/g' file.txt 
#                                     here ___^
```

Just remove it:

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)\.\([0-9][0-9]\)\.\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1\:\2\:\3/g' file.txt 
12:23:45
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!

Comment: @Success: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: Yes Toto! Thanks for your quick response :)